# NDSolve third order PDE with boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I am trying to solve following PDE involving a third derivative with respect to p:

```
a = 40; 
ps = 2*10^-5;
ic = u[0, p] == 0.3 E^(-0.06 (-(7/2) + p/2)^2);
bc = {u[t, -a] == 0, u[t, a] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][t, -a] == 0};
pde = - D[u[t, p], t] == ps D[u[t, p], {p, 3}] + I p^2/4 u[t, p];

solp = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, 60}, {p, -a, a}];
```

Then I animate the solution:

```
Animate[Plot[Evaluate[Abs[u[t, p] /. First[solp]]^2], {p, - a/2, a},  
PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}], {t, 0, 60, 0.05}]
```

The solution does not look like it should. For example, for very small ps, the solution should just be the initial function. Instead it is oscillating all over the place. How can I improve this code? My guess is, that I should choose different boundary conditions. I played around with them a lot, without success.

The physics behind this: I want to solve the time-dependent Schrödinger equation in momentum space. Situation: a particle wave packet collides with a weak x^3 potential. Any help very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to make the grid size small enough.
2. Based on the statement, I believe what you really need is periodic b.c..

The following code generates the same result as that in [Henrik's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216379/1871):

```
a = 10; 
ps = 2 10^-5;
ic = u[0, p] ==E^(-(p^2/4)) (2/π)^(1/4);
(*
bc = {u[t, -a] == 0, u[t, a] == 0, 
      Derivative[0, 1][u][t, -a] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][t, a] == 0};
 *)
pde = - D[u[t, p], t] == ps D[u[t, p], {p, 3}] + I p^2/4 u[t, p];

solp = NDSolveValue[{pde, ic, u[t,-a]==u[t,a](*bc*)}, u, {t, 0, 2Pi 10}, {p, -a, a}, 
         Method->{MethodOfLines, SpatialDiscretization -> 
           {TensorProductGrid, MinPoints->1200, MaxPoints->1200, DifferenceOrder->2}}];
Plot[(solp[2 Pi 10, p]//Abs)^2, {p,-3,2}, PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

BTW, it's interesting that `NDSolveValue` accepts the `bc` above i.e. one can set 4 b.c.s in `p` direction, the output is almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

We change the boundary conditions a bit, then we get

```
a = 40;
ps = 2*10^-5; f = 0.3 E^(-0.06 (-(7/2) + p/2)^2); f1 = D[f, p];
ic = u[0, p] == f;
bc = {u[t, -a] == f /. p -> -a, 
   Derivative[0, 1][u][t, -a] == f1 /. p -> -a, 
   Derivative[0, 1][u][t, a] == f1 /. p -> a};
pde = -D[u[t, p], t] == ps D[u[t, p], {p, 3}] + I p^2/4 u[t, p];

solp = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, 60}, {p, -a, a}];
```

Large and small scale visualization

```
{Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[u[t, p] /. First[solp]]^2], {p, -a, a}, {t, 0, 
   60}, ColorFunction -> Hue, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, AxesLabel -> Automatic, Boxed -> False], 
 Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[u[t, p] /. First[solp]]^2], {p, -a, a}, {t, 0, 
   1}, ColorFunction -> Hue, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, AxesLabel -> Automatic, Boxed -> False]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: thank you, but nothing changed for me. The Results don't make any sense. For example one would expect that a x^3 potential would reduce and then invert the average momentum over time. Also if you use ps ~ 10^-20, then there shouldn't be any oscillations. But there are a lot.

Comment: @Luke You are mistaken in your assumptions. The solution to equation ` -D[u[t, p], t] == I p^2/4 u[t, p]` has the form `Exp[-I p^2/4 t]`. These are oscillations with a frequency of `p^2/4`. This is what we see in the figures.

Comment: We plot the absolute value, which should not oscillate, right?

Comment: @Luke There is initial data. This is not a constant, but a package, which is also visible in the figures.

Comment: @ Alex I don't think initial data matters here as the time dependency is just a product with the initial wave packet. If you solve the Equation -D[u[t, p], t] == I p^2/4 u[t, p] ,   and plot Abs[u[t,p]], you will see that the wave packet just stays put with respect to time. That also makes physical sense since there is no potential present which could affect any momenta.

Comment: @Luke  Do you doubt or don’t understand what a numerical solution should be? Here we discuss the code. Physics can be discussed at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: sorry I don't wanted to be impolite. I just want to understand the truth.

Comment: I would appreciate to learn why the numerical solution does not match the analytic solution of the first order eq. -D[u[t, p], t] == I p^2/4 u[t, p], which is u(p,t) = u(p,0) Exp(i p^2/(2m)). The absolute value of that is: Abs[u(p,t)]^2 = |u(p,0)|^2 which is a non-oscillating gaussian.  This is for me a clear indication that there is something wrong with the numerical solution in the limit of ps ->0.  Please tell me what wrong with my thinking. I am not very good with numerics.

Comment: @Luke Do not forget about the boundary conditions. You can't just put `ps = 0` in this code.

Comment: Yeah I know. In my view the numerical solution should still converge to the analytic solution if I take ps to be extremely small. What am I missing?

Comment: @Luke You have lost the boundary conditions. It’s a pity that you started the discussion without thinking.

Comment: I very much appreciate that you try to help me but I do not understand what you mean. I am still convinced that the numerical solution does not make sense because it would violate mathematics (and physics). The result should not depend on our choice of boundary conditions as long as they are consistent with the searched solution...  I would be very happy if you explain to me what you exactly mean, so I can learn.

Comment: @Luke In other words, do you want to get a solution similar to your ideas about this solution?

Comment: Exactly. The reason is simple: I know how the solution has to look like since I simulated that thing before (with a python code and in position space). You may think that my ideas are wrong but I have good arguments :) For example, if you switch into position space and solve that things there and then Fourier-transform the solution it should match the momentum space solution. But it doesn't. And there are a few physical arguments (a x^3 potential changes the average momentum over time). I have more arguments but they don't fit here.

Comment: @Luke Let's check your idea here. Formulate the problem in the coordinate space as you did for Python. Write the code and place it in your topic.

Comment: @ Alex As you have already noticed, I posed the position space representation here: 
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216159/ndsolve-which-method-for-fast-moving-spreading-wavepackets?noredirect=1#comment552573_216159   Since the numerical problem completely different (third order almost constant wavepacket vs second order fast moving and spreading wavepacket), I thought it deserves a new question. Can you see now how the numerical solution in your answer can't be correct?