# NDSolve: Which method for fast moving/spreading wavepackets?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

I want to model a wave-packet interacting with a non-linear potential.

```
a = 20;
s = 0.8; (*width of wavepacket*) 
p0 = 3;  (*initial momentum of wavepacket*)
\[Psi][x_, s_] = (1/(2 \[Pi]))^(1/4) s^(-1/2) Exp[-1/4  (x/s)^2];
\[Psi]0 = \[Psi][x, s] Exp[I p0 x/2];
v0 = 2 10^-6 (*potential strength*);
pde = I D[u[t, x], t] == -D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] + v0 x^3 u[t, x];
ic = u[0., x] == \[Psi]0;
bc = {u[t, -2 a] == 0, u[t, 10 a] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, 60}, {x, -2 a, 10 a}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.2}}}];
```

This code works fine, as

```
Plot[Evaluate[Abs[u[t, x] /. First[sol]]^2] /. t -> 60, {x, -a, 10 a},
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: gives me the expected results]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[Abs[u[t, x] /. First[sol]]^2], {x, -a, 10 a}, {t, 0, 
  60}, ColorFunction -> Hue, Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 200, AxesLabel -> Automatic, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

The results are as expected. Why do I expect these results? Due to the initial momentum kick, the wave moves in positive x-direction while spreading. After a while it will interfere with itself since it experiences a non-linear potential.

Until here all good.

Now comes my problem: If I increase $p0$ (Ideally, I would like to increase it until 100) OR if I decrease $s$ (Ideally, I would like to decrease it until $0.01$), the code stops working.
Either it never finishes the calculation or the result looks completely messed up.

What can I do to increase numerical stability and speed in order to access a larger parameter space of $s$ and $p0$?

Comment: Did you continue this topic?https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215403/ndsolve-third-order-pde-with-boundary-conditions/215409?noredirect=1#comment551885_215409

Comment: Not really. I would love to know the answer to the question you linked to separately :) However, you noticed that the questions are related!

Comment: I mean you noticed correctly. Both topics are physically related, but numerically they probably need completely different approaches. I am just learning all this numerical solving of PDE stuff and so I would be very interested in how you would go and solve the problem from both perspectives (momentum and position-space).

Comment: Although the two problems are physically related, they are mathematically different. Firstly, other initial data, secondly, other boundary conditions. Explore the Fourier transform by the coordinate of solution `u[t,x]`.

Comment: yeah you are right. The nice thing is we can do a consistency check since their solutions are connected via Fourier transform (as you said).

Comment: The required parameters are extreme so I can't test at the moment (I'm now testing on Wolfram cloud free edition), but I believe the underlying issue is just the same as your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215403/1871). Keep in mind you probably need a rather dense grid for `s=0.01`.