# Solve third-order nonlinear differential equation with certain boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, physics

A (distinguished theoretical--not "computer savvy") physicist colleague (C. P.) of mine sent me this ("not quite up my alley") question.

[image]

I take it that $G$ is the gravitational constant.

The stack exchange pointed me to

[NDSolve third order PDE with boundary conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215403/ndsolve-third-order-pde-with-boundary-conditions)

but I think C. P. is thinking of exact--not numerical--solutions.

Assuming that $M_0$ is an independent constant, not simply M[0], my Mathematica formulation of the question put by C. P. is

```
DSolve[{(1/r^2) D[
  r^2 (1 - 2 G M[r]/r) D[Sqrt[M'[r]/(4 Pi  M0 r^2)], r], r] - 
M0^2 Sqrt[M'[r]/(4 Pi  M0 r^2)] == 0, M[0] == 0, M'[0] == 0, M''[0] == 0}, M[r], r]
```

Execution of the command does not yield any output. (Nor do limited attempts with NDSolve, with $G=1,M_0=1$,{r,0,1},....)

So, should this be the end of the story?

Comment: The text is very small in the image. Please write it in $\LaTeX$ or _Mathematica_ code.

Comment: Make that Mathematica code so that it can be copied and pasted.

Comment: Well, I was implicitly hoping (as may have been obvious) that a motivated (kindly) viewer might undertake the tasks indicated by flinty and Bob Hanlon. Otherwise, I will address these matters in good order. Perhaps I should just delete the question until this is done. I was just trying to pass on C. P.’s question to the community at large--since I have no particular expertise concerning it--while I am confident others are more skilled/interested in such matters.

Comment: If you could at least increase the image size much more, it will help. Right now, it is very hard to read even if someone attempts to code it in Mathematica, hard to read. Need extra credit to do it with such small font size.

Comment: Thanks, Nasser! I had, in fact, tried taking a screenshot and enlarging it--but didn't succeed it seemed. Any technical advice in how to accomplish such enlargement? Do I have to do it or can it be done by others on the basis of what's in the posted question. Needless to re-emphasize C. P. is not "computer-savvy", at least in the relevant matters at hand--nor am I, it would seem.

Comment: Trying to set up the problem in Mathematica,  but not certain if M_0 is meant to be an independent constant or the value of the function M at r = 0.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater - First, zoom in the document itself, then screenshot it to get a larger size.

Comment: Nondimensionalisation seems like a good route to take. It should not be difficult to undertake the task of highlighting the test in pdf, moving to Mathematica, and correcting any remnant errors that occur in the process—please, can you do this? It will be much better for others to seek to answer your question. Another possibility is that your computer savvy-less friend may perform this task, as they are likely familiar with Mathematica, or latex, at the very least.

Comment: Thanks, CA Trevillian! Sounds intriguing (that is, nondimensionalisation)--not in my standard tool kit, though. I'll pass it on to the original asker (C. P.) for possible feedback.

Answer (score -1):

I passed this question, along with the several accompanying comments, on back to the initial poser--who responded in an email with an attached pdf along with the remarks: "I attach the Mathematica file with graphs.  The way to solve it analytically is via an iteration procedure like the Hartree Fock method.  Yes, at r = 0, there is a singularity."

Although I seemed unable to post the indicated pdf I was sent here, I copied and executed the Mathematica commands. Here is a url displaying the resultant notebook.

[ThirdOrderDiffEq.nb](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/93ab421e-1147-4329-81a5-75587d8239ff)

Comment: Well, the notebook solves the problem numerically, so, the original asker actually just needs a numeric solution?

Comment: Thanks, xzczd! Seems so--I'll try to get  the asker to comment on this point. It was written that "The way to solve it analytically is via an iteration procedure like the Hartree Fock method". Is that a contradiction? Can an iterative, hopefully convergent process be termed analytic? Also, "had a friend(s?) of mine in [countries A and B]  who helped me with the Mathematica graphs.  I wanted to cross-reference their results to make sure they agreed." (Incidentally, just reading about Walter Kohn [creator of density functional theory--a relative of Hartree-Fock (not my expertise).)

Comment: I've now been informed of the origin of eq.(1) in the question. It appears as eq. (2.27) in the recent preprint, downloadable at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340966463_The_Geometrization_of_Quantum_Mechanics_the_Nonlinear_Klein-Gordon_Equation_Finsler_Gravity_and_Phase_Spaces

Comment: Also, been told , "An analytical solution would have been great.  As r goes to infinity,  the mass function goes to M_o = constant. M = M' = M'' are zero at r = 0."

Comment: "Can an iterative, hopefully convergent process be termed analytic?" If so, I'd argue solution produced by finite difference method is also an analytic solution because it's essentially a solution expressed as combination of piecewise polynomials :) .

Comment: OK, xzczd! So, might a "finite difference method" be of any particular relevance/value in the specific context of the question posed?

Comment: I doubt. I mentioned finite difference method (FDM) just because it's a classic numeric method for solving differential equations. Since `NDSolve` is able to handle the problem, I don't think we need a self implementation of FDM.